# $\|f\|_2\le\|f\|_4^{\frac{2}{3}}\|f\|_1^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove that $$
\|f\|_2\le\|f\|_4^{\frac{2}{3}}\|f\|_1^{\frac{1}{3}}
$$
I proved it by Holder inequality. But this is an exercise under "Interpolation". So I guess it can be proved using interpolation. But I can't see any of the two common interpolation theorems apply.

Answer (score 1):

The log-convexity of $L^p$-norms, used in the [Riesz-Thorin Interpolation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem), allows us to interpolate
$$
\|f\|_{p_\theta}\le\|f\|_{p_0}^{1-\theta}\|f\|_{p_1}^{\theta}
$$
where
$$
\frac1{p_\theta}=\frac{1-\theta}{p_0}+\frac{\theta}{p_1}
$$
Plug in $p_0=1$, $p_1=4$, and $\theta=\frac23$

Comment: OK. So this should be a lemma for the RT interpolation theorem, not a consequence of it?